# Update SPList.TemplateFeatureId

Tags: 2010, feature, splist

I need to update the TemplateFeatureId for a couple of lists in our SharePoint 2010 installation. The current TemplateFeatureId points to a feature that is no longer installed in the farm. Both SPList.SchemaXml and SPList.TemplateFeatureId are read-only properties, is there any other way to update the template feature ID, or do I have to create new lists and migrate all of the information?

The missing feature causes our third party backup software to crash. Updating the value in the content database is obviously not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are deploying a new SharePoint feature and you want these lists FeatureIds to point to this feature. Try changing the deployed feature ID to match the lists FeatureId.